Refreshing a LWC Component not working on LWR Page (Experience Cloud)
I have tried all the known ways of refreshing the LWC component after a record save.
These are ways I tried
1.Using refreshApex
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

wiredResult;
@wire(getUserDetails)
userRecord({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
         this.wiredResult = data;
         this.getWorkOrderAssignedToVendor(this.vendorAccountId);
    }
}

refreshPage is called from a child component. Showing a toast and calling the refreshApex on the onClose method of the toast. Here the toast works and also the onClose method is called as well.
refreshPage() {
    Toast.show({
        label: 'Quote has been created successfully',
        message: 'You can view the quote details in the Quotes tab.',
        mode: 'dismissable',
        variant: 'success',
        onclose: async () => {
            console.log('Toast is closed');
            return refreshApex(this.wiredResult)
        }
    }, this);
}


Using RefreshHandler

import { registerRefreshHandler, unregisterRefreshHandler } from 'lightning/refresh';
import { RefreshEvent } from "lightning/refresh";

refreshHandlerID
connectedCallback() {
    this.refreshHandlerID = registerRefreshHandler(this, this.refreshHandler);
}

disconnectedCallback() {
    unregisterRefreshHandler(this.refreshHandlerID);
}

refreshHandler() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
         console.log('resolving');
         resolve(true);
    });
} 

refreshPage() {
    Toast.show({
        label: 'Quote has been created successfully',
        message: 'You can view the quote details in the Quotes tab.',
        mode: 'dismissable',
        variant: 'success',
        onclose:() => {
            console.log('Toast is closed');
            this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());
        }
    }, this);
}

Anybody with experience please help.

Docs

The parameter you refresh with refreshApex() must be an object that was previously emitted by an Apex @wire.
[...]
To refresh a wired function, pass the argument the wired function receives (which is the wired value) to refreshApex()

This means that refreshApex needs the whole object you get from the wire adapter, not just its data property.
So you cannot use the destructuring assignment to get data and error as soon as possible. You must get the whole object, assign it to this.wiredResult, then extract its data property:
wiredResult;
@wire(getUserDetails)
userRecord(result) {
    this.wiredResult = result; // save the whole object
    const { error, data } = result; // extract the properties you need
    if (data) {
         this.getWorkOrderAssignedToVendor(this.vendorAccountId);
    } else if (error) {
         // handle the error
    }
}


Sorry for the late response. I just tried out your code, still it doesn't refresh. Just to reminder this is on an Experience site page.
